# Is it required to use "that" here?

Tags: grammar, that

First sentence:

> I contribute to projects I love.

Second sentence:

> I contribute to projects that I love.

I used to use the first one, but I am not sure if it is right or wrong when omitting "that".

Comment: "That" is often omitted, especially in conversation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relative pronoun standing at the front of a simple relative clause may be omitted unless it acts as the subject of the relative clause.

> <sup>ok</sup>I contribute to projects that I love.
>   <sup>ok</sup>I contribute to projects that support children.
>
> <sup>ok</sup>I contribute to projects I love.  *but not, in formal use,*
>   <sup>∗</sup> I contribute to projects support children.

- NOTE: In conversational use you will occasionally hear a subject relative omitted:

  > There are some projects support children I will not contribute to.
  >   I'll ask the man fixes my car about that.

  But this is not acceptable in formal use, and it is often not acceptable in conversation, either. Recognize it when it you hear it; but I advise you not to emulate it.

When there is other matter before the relative pronoun, it may not be omitted:

> This is the bag **in which** I keep my drumsticks.  *not* <sup>∗</sup>the bag **in** I keep my drumsticks
>   The exam, **passing which** is mandatory, is offered in the spring. *not* <sup>∗</sup>The exam, **passing** is mandatory ...

And the relative term may not be omitted when it acts as a determiner rather than a pronoun:

> The author **whose essay** you are reading was my teacher. *not* <sup>∗</sup>The author **essay** you are reading ...
>   He advised caution, **which advice** was unexpected. *not* <sup>∗</sup>...caution, **advice** was unexpected.