# Wording for error message when deleting an item

Tags: word-choice

When displaying a message to a user from our software, is it better to say:

"Choose the case note that you want to delete, and then try again."

or

"Choose the case note you want to delete, and then try again."

Ie. is the word "that" required?

Thanks!
Chris

Comment: *That* **can** be omitted. Search this site for related questions already answered. http://english.stackexchange.com/q/1095/14666

Comment: Select the case note that you want deleted, and then click the delete / submit button again.

Comment: *That* here is a relative pronoun, not a conjunction. I think a better duplicate is [Is it required to use *that* here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209718/is-it-required-to-use-that-here) but I'm open to alternatives.