# Is this use of "it likely" correct?

Tags: phrases

In the sentence "He never thought it likely that anyone would care about him," is the use of "it likely" correct or would it have to be "it was likely."

Comment: In this case "it likely" works like an adjective, instead of; objective, verb and adjective, which it would've been if it said "it was likely".

Comment: Araucaria has an indepth answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238150/he-thought-me-incapable-what-is-this-pattern/238203#238203) if you're interested.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, “thought it likely” in this case means the same as “supposed.” “Thought it was likely” is not an exact substitute.