# When should I use "that" to linking phrases?

Tags: phrases, that

For example:

I wish I was 16.

I wish that I was 16.

I know you love me.

I know that you love.

When would I put "that" or basically not put anything?

Comment: See this question: [Is it required to use "that" here?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209718/is-it-required-to-use-that-here?rq=1).

Comment: Yes, the answer there is a good short answer. But there's more, because _that_ is not merely a complementizer as here, but it also occurs in relative clauses like _the man (that) my mother is talking to_, and it has different rules in those constructions. Grammar isn't about individual words; it's about constructions.